# How to enable video autoplay with audio in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, youtube, autoplay

How do I enable video autoplay with audio in Chrome? The autoplay attribute does not work unless the video has a muted on it or the user has previously interacted with the site, BUT (and this is why the mods shouldn't remove this question or mark it as duplicate) YouTube somehow manages to autoplay videos even if you haven't interacted with the site before (just try opening any video in a new tab and if you switch to it, it will start automatically with audio). So how does YouTube manage to do that and how do I do the same?

Comment: browsers also have a whitelist of sites that can autoplay - https://blog.google/products/chrome/improving-autoplay-chrome/

Comment: That post does not say anything about a whitelist.

Comment: "If you don’t have browsing history, Chrome allows autoplay for over 1,000 sites where we see that the highest percentage of visitors play media with sound" ... youtube will be on that list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `visibilitychange` event to start the video:

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
  if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
    video.play();
  } else {
    video.pause();
  }
});
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. I also tried video.oncanplay with the same result

Comment: The function play.video() was just an example of how you can see if the tab is active. Here you could now make a function with fake click to start the video

Comment: Even if I do that fake click the video won't stop playing and the notification about the user needing to first interact with the site is gonna show up. I used to use that fake click workaround, but they patched it :(